# Hanna Barbara animation frame rate

Tags: animation

Question for old animators at Hanna Barbara: 1960s - 1980s. Do Hanna Barbara cartoons use 30 frames/s or 24 frames/s, and did they draw most animation on 2s for real 15 frames/s or 12 frames/s?

I guess 30 frame/s (15 frames/s on 2s) because US company make cartoons for TV (US TV during that time is NTSC ≈ 30 frames/s).

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful:
https://www.illustrationhistory.org/essays/hanna-barbera-the-architects-of-saturday-morning

> For a standard Disney feature, the film would be projected at
>   the standard 24 frames per second with each frame having different
>   animation. Planned animation provided for fewer frames, so that
>   instead of each frame having a new image, frames would be repeated two
>   or three times, resulting in just twelve or eight different frames per
>   second.
>
> This experimental approach is showcased in UPA’s most stylized
>   cartoon, Gerald McBoing Boing, for which they won an Academy Award in
>   1951. However, Hanna-Barbera adapted the technique out of necessity.

Comment: Very great history. I think they use 24 frame/second (film speed) from talk about why Hanna Barbara draw color cartoons: "Also, if television didn’t pan out, the color Hanna-Barbera cartoons would be readymade for exhibition in theaters." Theaters require 24 frame/second film speed, not 30 frame/second.

Comment: Then for television Hanna Barbara use "cine expansion (3:2 pulldown)"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember Hanna Barbara was not even on 2s!  They would hold frames for seconds at a time.  I often felt cheated on the hair bear bunch.